# web.xml filter-mapping not forwarding to struts

Tags: java, tomcat, struts2, web.xml

I am trying to do something trivial and can't see what I'm missing.  I have the following web.xml...

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.action</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

And when I use a URL like "http://localhost:8080/gallery.action", everything works just fine (because "gallery" is configured properly in struts.xml, etc, etc).

If, however, I hit "http://localhost:8080/gallery.do" instead - I get a 404 response.  Tomcat does not appear to be forwarding the request to struts as there is no logging on struts side.  Tomcat logs just show the 404.

I've tried changing the filter-mapping to *.blah and nothing works except for *.action.  I don't see any conflicting information in the default web.xml file.

Anyone know what I'm missing?

Comment: Is `struts.xml` configured to know what to do with `gallery.do`? Maybe the filter forwarding is working fine, buts Struts is misconfigured.

Comment: struts.xml is configured to handle the action name "gallery" ... but knows nothing about the extension .action (or .do).  It is my understanding that struts simply knocks off the extension to get the action name.

Comment: additionally, if I enter an invalid action name, struts performs plenty of logging... if I enter gallery.do I get absolutely no activity in the struts log so I think it is safe to assume it isn't getting ahold of it.

Comment: Replacing all other filter-mappings with the following...

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

gallery.action still works... but gallery.do or gallery.blah still won't.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently Struts2 only recognizes the .action extension by default and one needs to configure other extensions as desired using struts.properties file:

struts.action.extension=action,do,etc

This was very misleading given that most documentation discusses how to forward to struts using filter-mapping exclusively.

Answer (score -1):

That is because you do have a `<servlet-mapping>` for *.action, but no `<servlet-mapping>` for *.do

Comment: I don't have a servlet mapping for *.action or *.do  ... and I'm checking both web.xml and the servers default web.xml file.

Comment: i see. looked over the [struts2] tag